# ¿Como eliminar un registro cuando llegue una fecha especifica?

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos de nuevo, explico mi caso, tengo en una tabla cursos_disponibles los cursos que se van o se estan dictando actualmente cada curso con sus datos especificos entre ellos fecha de inicio y fecha final, lo que estoy pensando hacer es que al llegar la fecha final del curso, este se elimine automaticamente de mi tabla cursos_disponibles. Lo unico que se me ocurre es el condicional que podria ser asi:

```
if($row['fecha_final']==$fecha){
 $query = "DELETE FROM cursos_disponibles WHERE id = '$id'";
 $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Lo que no consigo es la manera de que se me elimine solo sin tener que darle a un boton o algo asi, que se elimine el curso automaticamente al llegar dicha fecha final. Gracias de antemano quien me auxilie.

Comment: No puedes, deberás limpiar manualmente los cursos vencidos, lo normal es utilizar [cron](https://blog.desdelinux.net/cron-crontab-explicados/) para estas tareas.

Comment: Puedes probar creando un procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos mysql y programar el scheduler que tiene mysql para que ejecute la tarea cada dia.

Comment: Por lo que veo es mas complicado de lo que pense.! Mejor me quedo con la forma manual.! Gracias igual

Comment: Como dice @JoseLuisMontañes, lo que necesitas en ese escenario es tener un store procedure en la base de datos, el cual se ejecute con un tarea diaria validando la fecha del servidor con la del curso. Otra cosa, para ello debes tener un campo en tu tabla de cursos del tipo date que represente la fecha fin del curso y algo mas, por buenas practicas, jamas se debe eliminar un dato de la bd a menos que sea estrictamente necesario. Lo que debes hacer es una eliminacion LOGICA, una columna Estado de Activo >> Inactivo. Saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si utilizas sessiones, puedes realizar una validacion que cada vez que entres haga una limpieza automatica si es que este cumple o no con la fecha.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
   //validamos si es realmente es valida la fecha
     CONSULTA A LA BASE POR FECHA Y COMPARAMOS CON OTRO IF
    etc...etc etc.
   //aca generamos la consulta del DELETE

}
```

Comment: Eso esta mucho mejor dogdark, es lo que intentare hacer, gracias.